# Next-JS Link tag not properly redirecting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to learn Next-JS, and I'm making a small, experimental project to familiarize myself. However, something seems to be going wrong with the Link tag. It does redirect to the friends page specified, but for some reason, the page content remains the same as it is on home. And clicking the test link while on this page, it attempts to redirect not to "#", but to "friends#".

Is there something I'm not understanding here? Any help would be appreciated. Here is my conde:

index.tsx:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

const HomePage = () => {

    // const handleClick = (e: Event) => {
    //     e.preventDefault()
    //     router.push('./friends')
    //     alert(router)
    return (
        <div className={styles.div}>
            <h1 className={styles.h1}>WELCOME TO HOME PAGE</h1>
            <ul className={styles.ul}>
                <li className={styles.li}>
                    <Link href='/friends'>
                        <a>FRIENDS</a>
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={styles.li}>
                    <Link href="#">
                        <a>TEST</a>
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )

}

export default HomePage
```

friends.tsx:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

const Friends = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>WELCOME TO FRIENDS</h1>
            <Link href="/">
                RETURN TO HOME
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Friends;
```

_app.tsx:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import HomePage from '../pages/index'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <HomePage />
}
export default MyApp
```

Screentshots of what I'm seeing are listed below. Note the URLs.

1. Home page
   [image]
2. Friends page
   [image]
3. After clicking the Test link, for which the href is currently "#"
   [image]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the `pages` folder/directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing the same page on all links is because you're always displaying the same component, which is `<Homepage />`. Instead, you need to render the `component` with `pageProps` to display the correct page according to the url.

The updated code of the `_App` component should be something like, where you need to display the `Component` available through the props.

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
export default MyApp
```

Please also take a look at the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) of the Next.js regarding the custom `_app`, to see available options/features out of the box.

**From docs:** The `Component` prop is the active page, so whenever you navigate between routes, `Component` will change to the new `page`. Therefore, any props you send to Component will be received by the page.

`pageProps` is an object with the initial props that were `preloaded` for your page by one of our data fetching methods, otherwise it's an empty object.